# Using scipy.odeint to solve coupled equations

Tags: numerical-analysis, python, ode, scipy, integration

I have a set of three coupled autonomous equations:
${y_{1}}\prime = y_{1}(\frac{\Omega_{m}}{y_{1}^3} + \frac{y_{3}^2}{6.0} + \frac{V(y_{2})}{2.H_{0}^2})$
$y_{2}\prime = y_{3}$
$y_{3}\prime = -3\frac{y_{1}\prime}{y_{1}}y_{3} - \frac{1}{H_{0}^2}\frac{\partial v(y2)}{\partial y_{2}}$
And I have used the following code to solve it using scipy.odeint:

```
def f(y,t):
    Xi = y[0]
    Yi = y[1]
    Zi = y[2]
    f0 = Xi*(onr/(Xi**3) + (H**2)*(Zi**2)/(2.0*rho_c) + (v0*np.exp(-l*Yi*k))/(rho_c))**(1.0/2.0)
    f1 =  Zi
    f2 =  -3*Zi*(H**2)*(onr/(Xi**3) + (H**2)*(Zi**2)/(2.0*rho_c) + (v0*np.exp(-l*Yi*k))/(rho_c))**0.5 + (l*k*v0*np.exp(-l*Yi*k))/(H**2)
    return [f0,f1,f2]

X0 = [1.0]
Y0 = [1.0]
Z0 = [c]
y0 = [X0,Y0,Z0]
t = np.linspace(start=1.0,stop=0.0,num=10001)

soln = odeint(f,y0,t)
X = soln[:,0]
Y = soln[:,1]
Z = soln[:,2]
```

But when I run it `ValueError: Initial condition y0 must be one-dimensional` shows up. What should I do? I am new to python and this is the first time I am using this. Any help or explanation here would be great.

Comment: Debugging help at SciComp.SE, as with StackOverflow, requires a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Code alone may not be enough for Readers to reproduce the error you report, and it would be worthwhile for you to try and get this error with fewer lines of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn’t have defined `X0`, `Y0`, and `Z0` as lists. As it stands, `y0` is a list of lists – i.e., two-dimensional. You can solve this by replacing the respective lines with:

```
X0 = 1.0
Y0 = 1.0
Z0 = c
```